# Jira Groovy Script Numeric Textbox value

Tags: groovy, jira

I use Jira 4.0

Jira has a meaning on numeric textbox.

I'm checking in the Groovy Script this space and I assign a variable as below.

```
 value = (String)WorkflowUtils.getFieldValueFromIssue(issue, WorkflowUtils.getFieldFromKey("customfield_10507")) ?: ""
```

If the value I assign to  “value” variable, which is written on customField, is greater than 200 as shown above, it should execute.

Example:

```
  if (value > 200)
  {}
  else if (value < 200)
  {}
```

My issue is that it detects it as smaller than 200 if the first digit of the number is smaller than 2, such as:

`value = 10 – 100 – 150 – 165 – 1000`

For instance; When I type `45,30,50,89` it accepts it as greater than `200`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution:

```
value = '56.0'
value2 = value.replace(".0", "");
int convertedNumber = Integer.valueOf(value2).intValue()
if (convertNumber > 200)
{}
else if (convertNumber < 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the value to `Integer`. Use `toInteger()` method on *non-empty* `String` object.

It should be something like:

```
def value = (String) WorkflowUtils.getFieldValueFromIssue(issue,WorkflowUtils.getFieldFromKey("customfield_10507"))
def valueNum = value?.isNumber() ? value.toInteger() : 0//You may change the default value
```

Comment: Hi Opal,how to syntax?